# How to debug S3 uploads using pre-signed URLs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

A while ago I implemented a PDF upload functionality in which my front-end calls my back-end, which calls [`getSignedUrl()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) in Amazon's JavaScript SDK to get a URL that the front-end should be able to upload a file to using a `PUT` request.

This has been working fine for a while now, and today, I tried to implement similar functionality for uploading an image (to a different S3 bucket). Unfortunately, although it looks to be set up the same, the `PUT` upload results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId><!-- A request ID --></RequestId>
    <HostId><!-- A host ID --></HostId>
</Error>
```

This isn't really helpful, so now I'm trying to figure out how best to debug this.

What I've checked:

- The bucket exists
- The bucket's CORS configuration is the same as that of the bucket to which uploading does work
- The bucket policy is the same as that of the working bucket, except that the resource it's `s3::GetObject` on refers to this new bucket
- The Access Control List is the same
- It's located in the correct region
- Pre-signed URL looks the same as working ones
- My browser is sending the same HTTP headers for the failing and working `PUT` requests
- The same goes for the `OPTIONS` request that gets sent first

What else can I check?

Comment: Did you check your crypto configuration? Or does it have any encryption at all? .withEncryptionMaterials(materialProvider)
                                                                .withCryptoConfiguration(
                                                                        new CryptoConfiguration().withAwsKmsRegion(
                                                                                Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)));

Also you can set the log level to debug to get more information from AWS S3 API

Comment: @Damien-Amen I don't think I've got any encryption set up. The SDK appears to work fine since it returns a pre-signed URL, it's just when I `PUT` to that URL (using Curl or simply the browser) that I get `AccessDenied`.

Comment: `AccessDenied` should rule out actual signing errors, because those should be met with `<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>`.  If you are signing with an IAM user, verify all policies attached to it or a group of which it is a member.  Any matching `Deny` cancels out a matching `Allow`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there was [one thing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) I had not checked properly:

> A pre-signed URL gives you access to the object identified in the URL, provided that the creator of the pre-signed URL has permissions to access that object. That is, if you receive a pre-signed URL to upload an object, you can upload the object only if the creator of the pre-signed URL has the necessary permissions to upload that object.

I generated the URL from an AWS Lambda function, for which I had to add an IAM Policy as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Although this is a good answer, in the sense that it solves the specific problem you had, I'm still holding out for an answer that more broadly answers "how can I debug a failing signed S3 link". Especially if I'm not the party that's having trouble.